# Getting DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT in my browserify react app

Tags: ssl, reactjs, browserify, npm-request

Having problems doing requests over invalid SSL from my `browserify` react app, I basically have this issue: https://github.com/request/request/issues/418 as I'm using `request`.

I have tried setting both `strictSSL=false` and `rejectUnauthorized=false` but it doesn't work.

The other solution was to set the environment variable `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` to 0. But I can't do that in my browserify/envify environment.

Help!

Comment: I think i managed to solve it. Will add an answer as soon as I'm allowed to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It turned out that the `strictSSL` setting did work. The problem was that `request` depends on the node package `https` which was not included in the browserify bundle. So as soon as I added `https` to the build and set the `strictSSL` setting to false it worked perfectly. Hope that helped somebody else!